# How to update customized table once payment transaction is successful?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to update a customized table when payment transaction is successfully done. Can anyone tell where is the function and how to update?

Comment: do u mean form payment gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event whene your order payment is success.

```
<events>
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    <observers>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <class>namespace/observer</class>
            <method>yourmethod</method>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </observers>
</checkout_onepage_controller_success_action></events>
```

Comment: Thanks Arshad, I will try and check. Sorry for delay reply.